# How to animate view to custom coordinates in OpenLayers 5?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, coordinates

Given just a basic ol.Map using OpenLayers 5

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ]
    target: 'map'
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});
```

I am attempting to allow for a user to enter a lat/lon coordinate in format *latitude, longitude* in decimal degrees.  I want to create an event that animates the map to move to that entered coordinate.

```
var panToPosition = function (latlon) { 
    if (/^(\-?[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{0,10}\s{0,10}\,\s{0,10}\-?[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{0,10})$/.test(latlon)) {                  
        var arrLatLon = latlon.split(',');
        var latitude = arrLatLon[0];
        var longitude = arrLatLon[1];
        var coords = [parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude)];
        Ext.GeoSpatialSearch.map.getView().animate({center: coords});               
    }
};
```

When this function fires, the map animates, but it always goes to [0,0], not the coordinate array I have selected.

I have found this example on another site

```
var coords = fromLonLat([parseFloat(latLong[1]), parseFloat(latLong[0])]);
```

but it is unusable as **fromLonLat** is not a usable function in OpenLayers 5, only 6+.  Why is it always going to 0,0 instead of the given coordinates?  If I do need to transform to a different projection, how do I do so?

Comment: You must use `ol.proj.fromLonLat` function, see docs at https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.fromLonLat

Comment: That was absolutely it!  Please post your comment as the answer, and I will mark it as accepted and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code you found is for ES6 code where there is first `import` of the `fromLonLat` function form `ol\proj` module, something like:

```
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
```

This code has either to be first compiled to run or run on node.js.

If you want to use function in vanilla JS environment, you have to reference function using the whole object path: `ol.proj.fromLonLat` (see docs at https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.fromLonLat).